# put the output of the shell script into a variable in a Java program

Tags: java, shell, output

Is there a way to get an output from a shell script program into a variable in Java program(not into the output file). The output of my shell script is the database query execution time and I need to assign that time value to a Java variable. (I am calling that shell script from Java program). And then I will need to do some other calculations on those values in Java.

Comment: Where are you getting that output?

Comment: I have this variable: TIME=`echo "$END - $START" in my shell script, and now I need to get the output of TIME and assign the value of the TIME variable to some other variable in Java class. I am doing fitness function for a genetic algorithm, so further by doing some computations on those Java variables obtained from shell script, i set the fitness and send it to ecj(ecj is a toolkit written in Java for evolutionary optimisation)

Comment: Are you executing the script through Java? If yes, you can get a `Process`' `InputStream` and read it/parse it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I'm calling shell script from Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Update to old question

Since Java 7 there is a new class which can easily deal with OS procecces: [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)
.
Let's assume we need to store the output of `ip_conf.bat` into a java `String`. Contents of `c:\tmp\ip_conf.bat`

```
@echo off
REM will go to standard output
ipconfig
REM will go to stadnard error
hey there!
```

You can read the input streams connected to the standard and error outputs of the subprocess:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\tmp\\ip_conf.bat");
Process p = pb.start();
String pOut = "";
try (InputStream stdOut = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStdOut = new BufferedInputStream(stdOut);
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

    int bytes = 0;
    while ((bytes = bufferedStdOut.read()) != -1) {
        result.write(bytes);
    }
    pOut = result.toString(Charset.defaultCharset().toString());
}
System.out.println(pOut);

InputStream stdErr = p.getErrorStream();
// same with the error stream ...

int exit = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Subprocess exited with " + exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the program that will help you store the full output of any script or any command into String object.**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

        String output = obj.executeCommand("sh /opt/yourScriptLocation/Script.sh");

        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just google it and there is a nice tutorial, full of examples here : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

I know people prefere copy/paste but let's respect other people's work and go on their website :p

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: One of the reasons for including the contents in your answer is that it will always remain here even if the original page goes offline.